# How to refresh airplay avalilable list by private api?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, airplay

I'm using iOS private api "MPAVRoutingController" to get avalilable airplay device list,like this:

```
MPAVRoutingController avCtrl = [[MPAVRoutingController alloc]init];
// get avalilable routes
NSArray *routes = avCtrl.availableRoutes;
```

But until I pop the iOS 7 "control center", the avalilable airplay device list doesn't update.
How to invoke refresh action by code?

Comment: Bit late, but you might want to call `fetchAvailableRoutesWithCompletionHandler:` the fetch the available routes.

Comment: This is still a bug in iOS 10, sadly.